# Google maps custom tiles magnification / digital zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I'm using this example

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image

As we see, the maximum zoom is set to 9

```
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 9,
  minZoom: 0,
```

so how can i "overzoom" to 10, 11 or whatever (of course losing quality) using the current (9x) tiles? my plans is to use Bing Tiles which usually have tiles up to 19x and i want to zoom it to 20 and 21

Comment: Using Bing Maps tiles in Google Maps is not allowed and is against the terms of use of Bing Maps and Google Maps.